# sql - How to get column EndDate from StartDate with several conditions on rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data table:

```
customer_id | place  | StartTime
---------------------------------------
1       | place1 | 2018-20-11 17:01
1       | place2 | 2018-20-11 17:48
1       | place3 | 2018-20-11 18:12
2       | place3 | 2018-18-11 15:26
2       | place1 | 2018-18-11 14:32
2       | place2 | 2018-18-11 15:02
2       | place4 | 2018-18-11 14:43
3       | place4 | 2018-20-11 17:01
```

I need calculate the end date of a session. 
The session begins with the first operation (done place1) and ends an hour after the last (done place3).
Between operations should be less than 1 hour.

There are some conditions also.
Operations should be performed in this order:

1. done place1
2. done place2
3. done place3

There may be other operations between these.

I need to get the above data into the following shape

```
customer_id | StartTime     | EndTime
---------------------------------------------------
1       | 2018-20-11 17:01  | 2018-20-11 18:12
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: The gun already out captain..

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I just thought it will be able to solve with ANSI SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by the following way by using builtin functions [MIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) and [MAX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp)

```
SELECT customer_id,MIN(StartTime),MAX(StartTime) AS EndTime from YourTable
group by customer_id
```

Comment: It is not correct for my way. Because I have the conditions above.

Answer (score 0):

use `max()` and `min()`

```
select customer_id,min(StartTime) as StartTime ,
max(StartTime) as endtime from t
group by customer_id
```